# kendoui grid select all

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I, working with MVC + kendoui grid and this is my code:

---

model

---

```
      public class User
         {
        [StringLength(9)]       
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]        
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<PoliciesHaglasha.Models.User>

@{    
    Layout = null;
    var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    var users = MvcHtmlString.Create(serializer.Serialize(Model));
}

         JsonUsers = @users;

        var  UsersSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            pageSize: 5,
            data: JsonUsers,            
            autoSync: true,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "UserId",
                    fields: {
                        UserId: { type: "number" ,editable: false, nullable: false },                      
                        UserName: { type: "string" , editable: false, nullable: false }                     
                    }
                }
            }
        });     
           $("#gridPolisot").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: PolisotSource,                        
            editable: true,
            scrollable: false,
            selectable: "row",
            sortable: true,            
            reorderable: true,           
            toolbar: [{ name: "save", text: "save" }],
            columns: [ 
                    { field:"IsSelected", title: "<input type='checkbox' id='chkSelectAll'>", width: "34px" ,template: "<input  type='checkbox' #= IsSelected ? checked='checked' : '' #/>"},                                    
                    { field:"UserId", title: "User Id", width: "20px", attributes: {"class": "KendoUITD"}},
                    { field:"UserName",title:"User Name",  width: "50px", attributes: {"class": "KendoUITD"}},              
                ],         
            },                         
        });
```

My questions are:

1)   How do I make the select all title checkbox to work?

2)  When I check/uncheck a checkbox it will return to the server

Thanks,

Comment: here is another solution

Select all check box from header[1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13810258/kendo-grid-how-to-check-all-checkboxes-of-selected-rows

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1)** You should use the [headerTemplate](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.headerTemplate) configuration option of the **grid**:

```
headerTemplate: "<input type='checkbox' id='chkSelectAll' onclick='checkAll(this)'/>"
```

Then add the "checkAll" function to the page:

```
function checkAll(ele) {
    var state = $(ele).is(':checked');
    var grid = $('#gridPolisot').data('kendoGrid');
    $.each(grid.dataSource.view(), function () {
        if (this['IsSelected'] != state) 
            this.dirty=true;
        this['IsSelected'] = state;
    });
    grid.refresh();
}
```

**2)** I'm not sure that I understand correctly what exactly you are trying to achieve, however if you need to sync the changes from the above function with the server then you can also call the **grid** [saveChanges method](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#methods-saveChanges).

Comment: Thank you Vladimir,

Your first example works perfect.
And about my second question is: I need to update the dataSource “IsSelected” property according to the user check / uncheck the checkbox, How do I do this?
Thanks